Character movement if either DEX or STR equal to SIZ and the other one greater than SIZ?
According to RAW:

Movement Rate (MOV)
An investigator can move a number of yards (or
meters) up to five times their MOV value in one round.
If both DEX and STR are each less than SIZ: MOV 7
If either STR or DEX is equal to or greater than SIZ, or if all three are equal: MOV 8
If both STR and DEX are each greater than SIZ: MOV 9

The text seems to be missing the case where a character has either STR or DEX equal to SIZ and the other one greater.
For example:

SIZ = 45
STR = 45
DEX = 60

Am I misreading something here? If not, what do you think is the most plausible RAI value?

Your example is covered by

If either STR or DEX is equal to or greater than SIZ, or if all three are equal: MOV 8


STR 45 is "equal to or greater than" SIZ 45 is true
DEX 60 is "equal to or greater than" SIZ 45 is true

You get MOV 8, if either of them is true (the first option of the clause quoted here), and not both are greater (because that is the third clause leading to MOV 9). This is the case.
Maybe the use of either ... or instead of simply or is misleading here, or not correct in formal logic terms. Looking at this formally, if this is an exclusive or, then the case where both are true, but not both are greater than SIZ is not covered.
I think what is intended is that effectively, this is your truth table



STR>SIZ
DEX>SIZ
STR=SIZ
DEX=SIZ
MOVE




False
False
False
False
7


False
False
True
False
8


False
False
False
True
8


False
False
True
True
8


True
False
False
False
8


True
False
False
True
8


False
True
True
False
8


False
True
False
False
8


True
True
False
False
9



You could state this more simply by saying if both of them are less than SIZ, your speed is 7, if both of them are greater than SIZ, your speed is 9, and in all other cases, your speed is 8.
PS. Thanks to @NeilSlater who provided material help to this answer.
The original poster @raven did contact customer support on the matter, and received an answer from Mike Mason that this interpretation is correct.

Thanks for taking the time to answer. If that was the case, the "or if all three are equal" part would be redundant. That, and the "either... or" makes me think the intention was for the second expression to be an exclusive or. But I guess we'll never know for sure.

@raven I think you are right. Even in that case though, a creature with those stats must have some speed. If one his higher and one the same, it woudl not make sense to be slower than one that has the same value as SIZ in both (which has MOV 8); and it also cannot be 9, as that is specifically limited to when you have both higher. So the only thing that makese sense to assign is 8.

FWIW I wrote to customer support and Mike Mason confirmed that your interpretation is the right one
